# Query for custom ordering in a single table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by

In MS SQL Server 2005 I have the following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE OFFICES(
   OFFICEID INT NOT NULL,
   OFFICENAME VARCHAR(100),
   HEADOFFICEID INT
 )

 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(1,'Germany',0);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(2,'France',0);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(3,'USA',0);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(115,'Berlin',1);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(116,'Munich',1);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(117,'Cologne',1);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(118,'Lyon',2);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(119,'Marseille',2);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(120,'Paris',2);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(121,'San Francisco',3);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(122,'Boston',3);
 INSERT INTO OFFICES VALUES(123,'Houston',3);
```

To better express what I want here's the result I need my `SELECT * FROM query` to return:

```
OFFICEID | OFFICENAME | HEADOFFICEID
--------   ----------   ------------
   1        Germany           0
  115       Berlin            1
  116       Munich            1
  117       Cologne           1
   2        France            0
  118       Lyon              2
  119       Marseille         2
  120       Paris             2
   3        USA               0
  121       San Francisco     3
  122       Boston            3
  123       Houston           3
```

As you can see the ordering is such that first comes the record  with the smallest `OFFICEID` with `HEADOFFICEID` value of 0 and then immediately the records that hold `OFFICEID` value of the aforementioned record as their `HEADOFFICEID`, of course also order by `OFFICEID`s. And so on..

Is this possible to do in a query? I'm suspecting it is, as relational algebra has very broad capabilities in terms of sorting and grouping but can't figure out how.

I know, this table design might seem wrong to you, but it's not my database, I just need to query against it. It' like a master-detail relationship in a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic that you want is to order by the head office or by the office id for the head office.  The rest is to put the head office first in the list and the rest by `officeid`.  You can do all this with `case` in the `order by` clause:

```
select *
from offices o
order by (case when headofficeid = 0 then officeid else headofficeid end),
         (case when headofficeid = 0 then 1 else 2 end),
         officeid;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a510/1) is a SQL Fiddle with the results.

Comment: This does exactly what I need, how can I not accept this? :) Thank you